# Who vs. Whom - Is there a faster way to identify which one to use besides the he/him method?

Tags: who-whom

> Use this he/him method to decide whether who or whom is correct:
>
> he = who
>       him = whom
>
> Examples:
>       Who/Whom wrote the letter?
>       He wrote the letter. Therefore, who is correct.
>
> Who/Whom should I vote for?
>       Should I vote for him? Therefore, whom is correct.

I understand the rule and can apply it, but I'm not efficient in applying it time-wise. This clearly shows in speech with a live person or a group.

For example, in speech I want to say:

> The doctor whom you recommended is not available for three months.

But it goes something like this:

> Speak: The doctor ...
>       *start of the 10 second pause*
>       Mental step 1: "he you recommended"
>       Mental step 2: "you recommended he"
>       Mental step 3: "you recommended him"
>       Mental step 4: him = whom
>       *end of the 10 second pause*
>       Speak: ... whom you recommended is not available for three months.

It's really awkward. Is there a faster way to identify whether to use *who* or *whom*?

Comment: If you really want to be fast, just use **who** all the time.  That is what most Americans do anyway, to be honest.

Comment: @stangdon - That's true, but in the example sentence, we don't need either word: _The doctor you recommended is not available for three months._

Comment: Not just Americans – most native speakers of English. I'm not sure why you're trying to force yourself to use a form that's in no way more correct than *who*, and risk sounding pompous. The only time it makes sense to use *whom* in conversational English is after a preposition (see the examples [here](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/whom)) where it sounds OK (and where it's the only grammatical option). Note that that doesn't mean you should force the preposition to the beginning of the clause just so that you could use a *whom* (in informal style).

Comment: @userr2684291 I'm following this guide which makes a clear distinction on when to use who/whom. https://grammarbook.com/grammar/whoVwhom.asp. Before James's answer, i wasn't aware that spoken language is less strict on that part.

Comment: The *he/him* method doesn't give you the right answer, so if it's slowing you down you might as well forget about it entirely.  Just learn when *who* and *whom* are possible and when they're appropriate.

Comment: @snailboat Why doesn't it give the right answer and how would one go about learning when who and whom are possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern standard spoken English, "who" is acceptable as both a subject and object pronoun.

> Who wrote the letter?
>
> Who should I vote for?
>
> The doctor who you recommended won't be available for three months.

These are both acceptable and *correct*. (Other ways may also be correct)

It is quite common to use "whom" when it follows a preposition:

> To whom should the letter be sent?

In written English, you can be rather more formal and use "whom" for the object pronoun. There is no difficulty in applying the "he/him" rule when writing formally, as you can pause and think about it.